# push notification not showing

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, push-notification

I am implementing invite friends from my app using facebook.All the things working fine but when I am inviting friend then push notification not showing in my friend notification.but notification send by app successfully.

How to solve this problem.

```
public class Trail extends Activity {


    private CallbackManager sCallbackManager;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trail);
        openDialogInvite(this);
    }
    public void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity) {
        String AppURl = "https://fb.me/Id number....";  //Generated from //fb developers

        String previewImageUrl = "";

        sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                    .setApplinkUrl(AppURl).setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                    .build();

            AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
            appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                            Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                            finish();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                            Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                        }
                    });

            appInviteDialog.show(content);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use GCM or some other SDK for sending push notification. And need to have a code in your app to receive the Push Notifcation and display it

Comment: @arshadkazmi42 I am not implementing push notification feature.I am implementing inviting friends feature from android app